# Do Summoners and Eidolons benefit from the same magic item?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, eidolon

Magic item slots are shared between summoner and eidolon. If one has a neck item, then the other cannot wear a different neck item.

Since the item slots are shared, does that mean the magic item effects are shared? For example, if the summoner wears a cloak of resistance, does the eidolon also benefit from the cloak?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, they don't

What is shared are the [magic item slots](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Items-Slots), not *magic items*.

> Of course, a character may carry or possess as many items of the same type as he wishes. However, additional items beyond those in the slots listed above have no effect.

In other words, between you and your eidolon, **you can only *benefit* from a single magic item per slot**, be that an amulet, or a magic armor, or a shoulder magic item, and so on. Each slot can either benefit your character, or your eidolon, but not both of you at the same time.

Also, since you (or your eidolon) can only benefit from a single magic item, that means that you could even use two items on the same slot, but you will have to pick one of them to benefit either of you. This is exactly like wearing multiple rings, but only two taking effect at one time, which is the example used by the [Link](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons/#TOC-Link-Ex-) ability:

> > the summoner and his eidolon share magic item slots. For example, if the summoner is wearing a ring, his eidolon can wear no more than one ring. In case of a conflict, the items worn by the summoner remain active, and those used by the eidolon become dormant.

He says that the "eidolon can wear no more than one ring" because the summoner is already using one ring, and we know you only have two magic ring slots.

Comment: In case of a conflict, what is the action to pick which one to use?

Comment: @MikeQ Im trying to look up an official reference, but its commonly accepted that the first item to take that slot will take effect. So if you need to switch, you take off the oldest items and place a new one on the same slot.

Comment: my question is as simple as this "if i buy one cloak and and thats all i have to my name as far as magic items and I wear it does my eidolon gain the effect of the cloak?"

Comment: @Ozuma I will try to make that clear, but the answer is on the title.

Comment: okay thank you, and sorry when i look at the answer i honestly don't look at the title cuz well it should just be in the answer XD. Anyway again thank you have a good one

Comment: does this mean that because magic items have an effect of "you" a summoner could wear a magic amulet and have the eidolon benefit from the effect, instead of yourself?

Comment: @ErinBailey No. It means that the eidolon could not wear another amulet and benefit from it.